# Нужна ли запятая после оборота "но не более чем"?

Tags: пунктуация

Срок проведения проверки может быть однократно продлен, но не более чем на 15 дней(,) при наличии значительного объема документов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Срок проведения проверки может быть однократно продлен, но не более чем на 15 дней, при наличии значительного объема документов.

Запятыми выделено уточняющее обстоятельство.

Другие варианты с тем же значением: Срок проведения проверки может быть однократно продлен при наличии значительного объема документов, но не более чем на 15 дней. При наличии значительного объема документов срок проведения проверки может быть однократно продлен, но не более чем на 15 дней.

Смысл однозначный: (1) если документов много, допускается однократное продление срока, (2)но в ограниченных пределах.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть продлён при наличии значительного объёма? Или не более чем на 15 дней при наличии значительного объёма?

Answer (score 0):

Если в исходном варианте запятую не поставить, то объём документов свяжется только с 15 днями, а если поставить, будет неясно, относится обьём документов формально ко всему предыдущему или только к части предложения до первой запятой; хотя смысла это и не меняет, создаётся впечатление, что последний оборот забыт и добавлен вдогонку (это допустимо только в устной форме). Поэтому лучше изменить порядок слов, например, так:

> В случае значительного объёма документов(,) срок проведения проверки
>   может быть однократно продлен, но не более чем на 15 дней.

или:

> В случае значительного объёма документов(,) срок проведения проверки
>   может быть продлен, но только однократно и не более чем на 15 дней.

(Первая запятая факультативна и нужна в случае, если условие продления требуется подчеркнуть.)